# Why can't one model access a specific object value from an associated model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Background: 
I'm using rails 4.0.4.  I have two models: comments and associated notifications for those comments. 
Comments has an after_create filter that sends notifications:

```
def send_notification
  Notification.comment_created(self)
end
```

The comment_created method inside Notifications model, currently working as expected on production:

```
def self.comment_created(comment)
  content = "[SENDER] replied \"#{n.truncate(comment.content, :length => 100, :omission => "...")}\" 
  create!(from_user: comment.user,
        to_user: comment.commentable.user,
        notifiable: comment.commentable,
        content: content,
        notification_type: 'REPLIED',
        comment_id: comment.id
        )
end
```

Now, I've successfully added pagination to the comments, so each comment has an attribute :comment_page_num (field type is integer).  This column and new values are showing up fine within the comments table, as well as rails console.

```
def create
  @comment = @post.comments.new(comment_params.merge(user: current_user))
  if @comment.save
    last_page = [(@post.comments.without_parent.length.to_f / 10).ceil, 1].max
    @comment.update_attribute(:comment_page_num, last_page)           
  end
end
```

To make the :comment_page_num attribute accessible, I've whitelisted it within the comments controller:

```
def comment_params
  params.require(:comment).permit(:comment_page_num, :user_id, :post_id, :parent_id, :content)
end
```

Now I'm trying to copy this value into the created Notification:

```
def self.comment_created(comment)
  content = "[SENDER] replied \"#{n.truncate(comment.content, :length => 100, :omission => "...")}\" 
  create!(from_user: comment.user,
        to_user: comment.commentable.user,
        notifiable: comment.commentable,
        content: content,
        notification_type: 'REPLIED',
        comment_id: comment.id,
        page_num: comment.comment_page_num
        )
end
```

But this keeps returning an empty value for page_num:

```
<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Notification id: 923517, from_user_id: 2921, to_user_id: 2, notifiable_id: 47812, notifiable_type: "Post", notification_type: "REPLIED", content: "[SENDER] replied \"6:41\" to your post [SUBJECT]", is_read: nil, created_at: "2016-01-03 13:41:07", updated_at: "2016-01-03 13:41:07", comment_id: 76705, page_num: nil>]
```

When I replace comment.comment_page_num with any other comment attribute that's an integer (like comment.user-id or comment.notifiable_id), it works fine.  It seems that only the comment_page_num attribute is inaccessible within this model.  What am I missing?

Comment: I am wondering how is value for attribute comment_page_num assigned to comment. Do you send comment_page_num as an attribute/hidden_attribute with the value in the comment form ?

Comment: @SandeshSoni Thanks for asking.  The value is generated during creation based on total # of comments (in the thread) divided by 10.  I just edited the create method into the question.

Comment: I suspect the value of page_no is not stored. https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/a7f4b0a1231bf3c65db2ad4066da78c3da5ffb01
Its a different thing, why would one store page no.

Comment: @SandeshSoni found the mistake and added to answer below.  Indeed, the value wasn't stored correctly.  Weird thing is the value was still showing up in the comments model and DB table, which is what threw me off.

Comment: I was about to suggest
last_page = [((@post.comments.without_parent.length + 1).to_f / 10).ceil, 1].max
  @comment = @post.comments.new(comment_params.merge({user: current_user, comment_page_num: last_page}))

Comment: @SandeshSoni thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Just found the mistake.  It's because I applied

```
update_attribute(:comment_page_num, last_page)
```

after

```
if @comment.save
```

Changed to this, and it now works:

```
def create
  @comment = @post.comments.new(comment_params.merge(user: current_user))
  last_page = [(@post.comments.without_parent.length.to_f / 10).ceil, 1].max
  @comment.update_attribute(:comment_page_num, last_page)       
  if @comment.save
    ....
  end  
end
```

Still not sure why it wasn't accessible, if the value was showing up correctly in the comments model and comments table in the DB (in console, this was showing the correct value:

```
Comment.find_by_id(4292).comment_page_num
```